# How to declare two data types containing same variable in haskell?

Tags: haskell

In a module, I want to add two classes like this.

```
data Person = Person { name :: String -- and some other details
                     } 

data PetAnimal = PetAnimal { name :: String  
                           }
```

I assumed this would work but ghc complains about multiple declrations of name. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: In GHC 8, you can use the `DuplicateRecordFields` extension to allow this by adding `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` to the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, I am using 7.6.3. 
Anyways, apart from getting it to work, I would like to understand the philosophy as to why this does not work by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here, I believe, is that Haskell defines access functions for all the fields in a record, so you get one function

```
name :: Person -> String
```

and then one

```
name :: PetAnimal -> String
```

which is what the compiler does not like.

You could change one or both of the names, or put them in different modules.

Answer (score 1):

Type Classes are another way to achieve a common interface that you may consider.

```
data Person = Person { personname :: String -- and some other details
                     } 

data PetAnimal = PetAnimal { petanimalname :: String  
                           } 

class HasName a where
  name :: a -> String

instance HasName PetAnimal where
   name = petanimalname

instance HasName Person where
   name = personname
```